# Titanium android map coming with a fix size

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, titanium, titanium-mobile

In my titanium android application, i want to show a map with certain location marked. When i execute app, locations coming accurately with the map, but map come with a fix size. I am unable to navigate to any other place, because when i drag the map it start showing gray tiles after a fixed width and height. Here the map is not loading with draging of screen, as it usually loads. My code is shown below. Please suggest. Thanks.

```
var mapview = Titanium.Map.createView({
mapType: Titanium.Map.STANDARD_TYPE,

region: {latitude:30.2878560000, longitude:-81.5689450000,
latitudeDelta:1.05, longitudeDelta:1.05,
},

top:0,
width:200,
height:300,

animate:true,
regionFit:true,
userLocation:true,
regionFit:true

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure but this can be done with eliminating **fullscreen** from the window code.

```
fullscreen:true,
```

Remove this property if you have wrote. It resolved my very similar problem.